# Is there a good method for parsing the user-agent string?

Tags: java, parsing, user-agent

I have a `Java` module that receives the `User-Agent` string from an end user's browser needs to behave slightly differently depending on the type of browser, the version of the browser and maybe even the operating system.
E.g.: `{"FireFox", "7.0", "Win7"}`, `{"Safari", "3.2", "iOS9"}`

I understood that the `User-Agent` string can vary in its format for the exact same configuration due to different plug-in installations etc.

My questions:

1. Is the structure of the `User-Agent` well defined? If yes - where can I find it exactly? (From my understanding of the RFC there is not much standardization here).
2. Assuming the question for #1 is `No` - is there a proper way to parse it to get the info I need?
3. Is there a better way to get the info I need other than the `User-Agent` string?

Important note - I'm talking about a web-app, so my data collection abilities are limited to `javascript`.

Comment: *"needs to behave slightly differently"*  Differently how, **specifically?**  There are many techniques for supplying the right content/form of content to end-users based on need.  Very few of them rely on parsing the inherently untrustworthy UA string.

Comment: _"my data collection abilities are limited to javascript"_ Java or Javascript?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - can you elaborate a bit more on what form of information gathering techniques you are referring to? I'm limited to a non-interactive method.

Comment: @TedHopp - `JavaScript` for collecting, `Java` for parsing - your answer fits my needs - but I'm not sure my needs are the right choice of action :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson - no need to get snappy, if I misinterpreted your comment it is not due to lack of attention. Unfortunately I cannot provide information on why I need this - if that is not enough to get help, I'll just have to make do with what I've got.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For Java, take a look at [User-Agent-Utils](http://www.bitwalker.eu/software/user-agent-utils). It's fairly compact (< 50kB) and has no dependencies.

Note although the latest release is quite recent (1.21, released 2018-01-24), the library's page states:

> Warning: This project is end-of-life and will not be updated regularly any longer

And on the [github page](https://github.com/haraldwalker/user-agent-utils) it says:

> **EOL WARNING**
>
> This library has reached end-of-life and will not see regular updates
>   any longer.
>
> Version 1.21 was the last official release in 2018.

Comment: These pages now say "EOL WARNING

This library has reached end-of-life!
Version 1.20 is the last official release.
"

Comment: @NielsBasjes - That's interesting. Some of the other answers here have pointers to other libraries. Harald Walker's [blog post](http://www.bitwalker.eu/blog/user-agent-utils-1-20-final-release) on why he stopped further development of User Agent Util is definitely worth a read.

Comment: @TedHopp: Yes the lies in the useragents are a major problem. See also my blog on the subject https://techlab.bol.com/making-sense-user-agent-string/ which is about https://github.com/nielsbasjes/yauaa and the architecture of that analyzer.

Comment: @NielsBasjes - Nice post! I see that you posted an answer here about your library (+1 from me for that). You might want to include a link to your blog post in the answer itself (and in the README.md file at github, as well).

Answer (score 32):

Have a look at the Java library I wrote for this purpose: [Yauaa](https://github.com/nielsbasjes/yauaa)

I made a very simple servlet where you can try it out to see if it gives the answers you are looking for: https://try.yauaa.basjes.nl/

It is Apache 2 licensed and published into Maven so using it in a Java application is really easy. It is currently used in production on one of the busiest websites of the Netherlands (where I work).

See this blog about this https://techlab.bol.com/making-sense-user-agent-string/

Comment: Thanks, while this is a fairly old question (from 2011) - I may have a need for it yet - the built-in LRU is a good addition to my current needs, does it have a configurable size?

Comment: Yes, you can set the size and even disable it.

Answer (score 12):

> 1. Is the structure of the User-Agent well defined? If yes - where can I find it exactly? (From my understanding of the RFC there is not much
>      standardization here).

No, the structure of an User-Agent string is not standardized but is very similar between different agents. Although they are very similar, it is still necessary to use multiple patterns for detection.

> 2. Assuming the question for #1 is No - is there a proper way to
>      parse it to get the info I need?

You can try the library [UADetector](http://uadetector.sourceforge.net/). It is a wrapper for the User-Agent-Database of [user-agent-string.info](http://user-agent-string.info/).

> 3. Is there a better way to get the info I need other than the User-Agent string?

I would not say it is a better or worse way, but another way to detect user agents is the client-side use of JavaScript to collect informations about the User-Agent and submitting it via hidden HTML inputs or XmlHttpRequest to your backend. It all depends on what you want to identify. For accurate detection of webcrawlers JavaScript won't be able to help.