# Get name and version of web browser using Java

Tags: java, web, servlets, browser

I see in other questions that using this you can get the web browser name and version, but I receive all the web browsers name and version, not the web browser that I am really using, for example, this is the code:

```
 HttpServletRequest origRequest = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
    String agent = origRequest.getHeader("user-agent");
    
    logger.error("Web browser:" + agent);
```

And the result is:

```
Web browser: ExploradorMozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36
```

How can I get only the name and version that I'm really using at this moment.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a good method for parsing the user-agent string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796415/is-there-a-good-method-for-parsing-the-user-agent-string)

Comment: I cannot use external libraries

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236482/java-or-pig-regex-to-strip-out-values-from-useragent-string

Comment: in the answers they of your post, they said that you have "just the first two semicolon-separated terms" , and I'm using Chrome on my tests, so the web browser is wrong with this solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java or Pig regex to strip out values from UserAgent string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236482/java-or-pig-regex-to-strip-out-values-from-useragent-string)

Comment: no, my question is how to get the actual web browser I'm using with Java. the question you post is the same as Reporter, and the only said how to parse the first value, but in my chase, the first value will be Mozilla and I'm using Chrome, so that solution don't work for me

Comment: Look at the internet. May https://jonlabelle.com/snippets/view/yaml/browser-user-agent-regular-expressions ? or http://www.java2s.com/example/java/network/get-browser-name-from-user-agent-via-regex.html